# Разбор предложения "С первым снегом вас!"

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

"Ребята! С первым снегом вас!"

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 3):

В школе это эллиптическое предложение с пропуском сказуемого, которое не нужно восстанавливать ни с помощью контекста, ни с помощью ситуации, семантически оно полное, смысл ясен, только конструктивно неполное.

Если это колледж или вуз, то такие предложения называют фразеологизированными: Спокойной ночи! Счастливого пути! Доброго здоровья! Это готовые речевые штампы.

Предложения-штампы употребляются в речи как формулы выражения внимания, пожеланий, а также используются для привлечения внимания собеседника. Поэтому их конкретное содержание в большей или меньшей степени утрачивается, стирается, лексическое значение отдельных слов хотя и сохраняется, но в значительной степени перекрывается общим функциональным значением всей единицы.

https://studopedia.ru/3_79399_frazeologizirovannie-predlozheniya.html

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что это **неполное предложение** — простое, с неназванными главными членами (подлежащим и сказуемым), восклицательное.

[Я поздравляю; мы поздравляем] C первым снегом вас!

*Мы

друг друга

звонким смехом

поздравляем

с первым снегом.*
С. Островский. Смехотворение

[Типы неполных предложений](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-162.htm)

Answer (score 1):

**С первым снегом вас!**

Это неполное **ситуативное** предложение, когда пропущенные члены ясны не из контекста, а из ситуации.

Вариант полного предложения: *Поздравляем вас с первым снегом!*

Инверсия позволяет сделать ударение на  сочетании "с первым снегом".

Comment: "Поздравляем вас с первым снегом!" — полное? А где подлежащее?

Comment: А подлежащего нет. Это односоставное (определенно-личное) предложение.

Comment: ОК Спасибо! Односоставные предложения могут быть полными.

Comment: А какая ситуация здесь нужна? Это можно произнести и у окна дома, и на улице, обращаясь к друзьям или прохожим, и где угодно кому угодно, и все поймут. Это готовая формула, всем понятная. Ситуативное было бы в таком случае: - Подайте коробочку! - Какую? - Красную. Последняя реплика - ситуативно неполное предложение, понятное только в этой ситуации, понятно, что нужно подать красную коробку,  а если бы кофточку просили - было бы о кофточке.

Comment: Ну да, даже в письме можно написать. Готовые формы как раз и привязаны к ситуациям. В данном случае ситуация связана с первым снегом. Предложение-штамп для поздравлений и пожеланий? Можно так назвать, но только не эллиптическое предложение. (.В отличие от эллиптических, предложения-штампы утратили соотносительность с глагольными конструкциями). К тому же « штамп» – это всего лишь название темы предложения, но не определение его структуры и грамматики.